# Regexp for the inverse of a match

Tags: regular-expressions

Given a regexp A, how do I derive the inverse regexp B such that given any text exactly one of the two regexes will match it.

For example in the below example:

```
(rx (or (group ---regexpA---) ; a match
        (group ---regexpB---))) ; every group of text that's not matched by above
```

It should be the case that the concatenation of the list of matches should be exactly the contents of the buffer.

```
(string= (buffer-string)
         (let (string)
           (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
             (setq string (concat string
                                  (or (match-string-no-properties 1)
                                      (match-string-no-properties 2)))))
           string))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is maybe an [X Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you're really trying to do?

Except for some simple regexps (e.g. character classes, `[...]`, where `[^...]` means *not*), a regexp *cannot* find a **non**-match. A regexp is not negative.

The way to get the effect of negative matching is to use Elisp to first match and then take the complement, that is, ignore or exclude whatever matches, using Lisp code to do what you want with the text that didn't match a regexp.

Comment: Ok I'll consider posting what I am trying to do in a separate question.